# redis could not get remote connection

Tags: redis

I have annotated bind 127.0.0.1 in redis.conf
and set protected mode no,
but when I try to connect redis from another host,
I can't get connected.
I have closed my firewall.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCfn5.png)

Comment: what port are u trying to connect to. redis is available by default on 6379 ? where is ur cluster running? locally ?

Comment: You set loopback IP (127.0.0.1) for connections, thus only local-PC running apps can connect to redis port. You need to bind external IP of your pc, not 127.0.0.1